# Stationary values

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to go on and answer this question, I appreciate any help.

Show that $$f(x) = \ln(3x^2 - 2x -1) - 4x^2$$ has a stationary value when $x$ satisfies 
$$12x^3 - 8x^2 - 7x + 1 =0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a stationary value, one must first find the first derivative of $f(x)$. In doing so you should find
$$f'(x) = \frac{6x-2}{3x^{2}-2x-1}-8x$$
For the left hand side to be zero (i.e., a stationary value)
$$0=\frac{6x-2}{3x^{2}-2x-1}-8x$$
Implying 
$$6x-2=8x(3x^{2}-2x-1)$$
Multiply this out and re-arrange and you should find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=\frac{6x-2}{3x^2-2x-1}-8x=0$$

rearrange to get the given equation